# Using Grial UIKit with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to use Grial UIkit with my existing Xamarin forms App, but I am facing some issues, can anyone tell me what steps I need to follow to use this kit with an existing project. Currently I am following this link

https://github.com/UXDivers/Grial-UI-Kit-Support/wiki/Adding-Grial-on-existing-project:-Setting-up-Grial-theme-required-files#assemblyinfocs

But I am getting this error

Field 'Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage.ContentProperty' not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. This issue was coming because of the different versions of xamarin forms used in my project and Grial UI kit.